# android broadcast permission

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, broadcastreceiver

```
   <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Manifests

```
 var intent2 = Intent(requireActivity(), MyReceiver::class.java)
        intent2.putExtra("Test", "value")
        intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)





  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            var st = intent.getStringExtra("Test")
        
            if (intent.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) {
                var st = intent.getStringExtra("Test")
                var toast = Toast.makeText(context, st, Toast.LENGTH_LONG) //
                toast.show()
            }

}
```

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED from pid=3604, uid=10091

I get an error like this
I searched but couldn't find a solution
Please help...

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` is protected action, only system applications are allowed to send it.

Comment: So what should I do? I just started, so I don’t know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

You cannot use `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` because it's a private android action, so you need to create your custom action.

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.receiver.RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Then you need to register for your activity before using it. Usually, I put in the onCreate method.

```
private fun registerReceiver(){
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(MyReceiver.RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION)

        val customReceiver = MyReceiver()
        registerReceiver(customReceiver, filter)
    }
```

And when you called to share your message, use the following code.

```
companion object {
        const val RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION = "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.receiver.RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION"
    }

private fun callCustomBroadcast(message: String) {
        val intent = Intent(RECEIVE_MESSAGE_ACTION)
        intent.putExtra("mymessage", message)
        sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
```